# Why delete an event from a Unity delegate event?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interface

I am currently reviewing the code.

During the review, I got an questions.

This is the code content of the part receiving the event.

EventManager.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

namespace wp.events
{
    delegate void WordEventDelegate(object obj, EventArgs e); // 델리게이트 선언
    class EventManager : WordGameSingleton<EventManager>  // 싱글톤 상속받음
    {
        public event  WordEventDelegate wordeSendEvent; // 이벤트 델리게이트 선언

        public void dispatchEvent(object obj, EventTypes type, Hashtable data = null) // 이벤트 수신 
        {
            GameEvent evt = new GameEvent ();
            evt.obj = obj; // 받은 이벤트의 객체
            evt.eventType = type; // 받은 이벤트의 타입
            evt.evetData = data; // 받은 이벤트의 데이터

            wordeSendEvent (this, evt);
        }

        public void addEvent(WordEventDelegate wedlistener) // 이벤트를 추가함
        {
            wordeSendEvent += wedlistener;
        }

        public void removeEvent(WordEventDelegate wedlistener) // 이벤트를 삭제함
        {
            wordeSendEvent -= wedlistener;
        }
    }
}
```

I set the EventTypes to enum in code.

for example..

```
public enum EventTypes
{
    GAME_INIT,
    ...
}
```

Registering an event is implemented as an interface, and object and EventArgs are set as parameters.

for example..

```
interface IWordGame
{
    void onHandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e);
}
```

And when the game is started, it adds an event inside the init () function.

for example..

```
public void init()
{
    EventManager.Instance.addEvent(onHandleEvent);
}
```

I understood that even adding events.
but, I do not know why deleted the added event again.

That part is shown in the code below.

```
public void onHandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GameEvent evt = e as GameEvent;
    Debug.Log(">> event type : " + evt.type);
    switch(evt.type)
    {
        case EventTypes.INTRO_STAR:
            EventManager.Instance.removeEvent(onHandleEvent);
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm curious. I do not understand why I want to delete the added event.

Could you clarify this part?

Please help me as a beginner.

Comment: I hope your code review also raised the point that this code uses Java naming conventions rather than those of C#.

Comment: Also that methods named `On*`, are, by convention, used to raise an event rather than handle it. Your `onHandleEvent` is clearly handling the event. It should properly be called `HandleEvent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern is used to listen to any specific event only for one time. For example in your case Initialization of game. If you won't unsubscribe the handler from the event, it would keep receiving the calls whenever the event is fired.

Here is what your code do:

1. Subscribe to Event.
2. Handle first Event.
3. Unsubscribe from Event after first call as the purpose is served.

This will subscribe/register to EventManagers's `wordeSendEvent`:

```
public void init()
{
    EventManager.Instance.addEvent(onHandleEvent); // subscribing
}
```

onHandleEvent is listener to `wordeSendEvent`. When this event is fired for first time `onHandleEvent` will be called.

and it will unsubscribe to the EventManager's `wordeSendEvent`:

```
case EventTypes.INTRO_STAR:
    EventManager.Instance.removeEvent(onHandleEvent); // unsubscribing
break;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does the beginning of the event mean that I have registered an event?